# Issue adding new shipping carriers for package tracking

Tags: configuration, shipping-methods, magento-1.14

fairly new Magento dev here.. I'm adding two new carriers to our Magento EE instance, Apex and OnTrac. The carrier records are attached to the shipment by a separate process handled by our ERP system and then imported into Magento, so we don't need to worry about anything being customer facing. **All I need is to enable tracking info for these carriers**.

Under the below configuration, APEX and OnTrac now display in system>configuration, but only APEX shows in the Shipping and Tracking Information box in Sales>Shipments, and if shipments are imported into Magento from our ERP, that control is empty.

Here's my code, what am I missing?

app/etc/modules/Foo_Shipping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Shipping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </Foo_Shipping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Foo/Shipping/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Shipping>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Foo_Shipping>
    </modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <foo_shipping>
            <class>Foo_Shipping_Model</class>
        </foo_shipping>
    </models>
    <sales>
        <shipping>
            <carriers>
                <ontrac>
                    <class>Foo_Shipping_Model_Carrier_OnTrac</class>
                </ontrac>
                <apex>
                    <class>Foo_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Apex</class>
                </apex>
            </carriers>
        </shipping>
    </sales>
</global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <ontrac>
                ...
            </ontrac>
            <apex>
               ...
            </apex>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Foo/Shipping/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <ontrac translate="label" module="shipping">
                    <label>OnTrac</label>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        ...
                    </fields>
                </ontrac>
                <apex translate="label" module="shipping">
                    <label>APEX</label>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                          ...
                    </fields>
                </apex>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Foo/Shipping/Model/Carrier/OnTrac.php

```
class Foo_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Ontrac
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'ontrac';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    public function isTrackingAvailable()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array(); //shell, we won't use this logic for this carrier
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Foo/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Apex.php

```
class Foo_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Apex
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'apex';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    public function isTrackingAvailable()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array(); //shell, we won't use this logic for this carrier
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `collectRates()` method you are returning rate result object but without adding any actual rates. You need to add at least 1 to show it on front end:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    /** @var Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method $rate */
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $rate->setMethod('apex_main');
    $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('method_title'));
    $rate->setPrice($this->getMethodPrice(0));
    $rate->setCost(0);

    $result->append($rate);

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Calculate price considering free shipping and handling fee
 *
 * @param string $cost
 * @param string $method
 * @return float|string
 */
 public function getMethodPrice($cost)
 {
    return $method == $this->getConfigData($this->_freeMethod)
        && $this->getConfigFlag('free_shipping_enable')
        && $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal') <= $this->_rawRequest->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()
        ? '0.00'
        : $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost);
 }
```

You can simplify or extend logic of settings price and names according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Although, there was no change to the shipment tracking page after implementing this logic and I don't need it to show on the front end. What is needed to have a shipping carrier appear in the package tracking list on the View Shipment page?

Comment: Fixed this by 2 steps: renaming my OnTrac.php file to Ontrac.php, since it was named ontrac in my configs, the casing made the carrier appear where I needed it. I also added a getTrackingInfo() function to get tracking information in order for this to be functional

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same ... add new carriers for internal use only (not visible on frontend)

For your carriers model this should be enough:

```
protected $_code = 'ontrac';

public function isTrackingAvailable()
{
    return true;
}

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    return null;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array();
}

/**
 * @param string $tracking
 * @return false|Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function getTrackingInfo($tracking)
{
    $trackData = array(
        'carrier'       => $this->getCarrierCode(),
        'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
        'tracking'      => $tracking,
        'url'           => 'http://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&idc=' . $tracking // german DHL tracking URL
    );

    return Mage::getModel('shipping/tracking_result_status', $trackData);
}
```

In config.xml I just set carrier title and model (i've no need for backend settings):

```
<default>
    <carriers>
        <ontrac>
            <title>Your title</title>
            <model>foo_shipping/carrier_ontrac</model>
        </ontrac>
        ...
    </carriers>
</default>
```